# Can I have a newline in balloonevalterm expressions?

Tags: terminal, balloon

I'm trying to use balloon text for my C macros, say, `true` and `false` as follows in the terminal version.

```
function! MyBalloonExpr()
  let macros = {
\ 'true':"true\n1",
\ 'false':"false\n0",
\ }
  return get(macros, v:beval_text, '')
endfunction
set balloonexpr=MyBalloonExpr()
set ballooneval
set balloonevalterm
```

The idea is to display a two-line balloon, with the first line the macro name and the second line the macro value, e.g.

```
true
1
```

However, it gets displayed as `true^@1` as if the newline were a NUL byte (^@). What am I missing? Are multi-line balloon texts possible in the terminal (they do work in the GUI version)? Is this a bug?
I'm using vim 8.1.2269 compiled today.

Comment: This has been fixed as of https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you've seen this, but [`:help 'balloonexpr'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27balloonexpr%27) says this:

> To check whether line breaks in the balloon text work use this check:
>
> ```
>  if has("balloon_multiline")
> ```
>
> When they are supported "\n" characters will start a new line.  If the
>     expression evaluates to a |List| this is equal to using each List item
>     as a string and putting "\n" in between them.

So if `:echo has("balloon_multiline")` returns `0` in your terminal, you're outta luck. If it returns `1`, works in normal windows, but not in terminal windows, that looks like a bug; please report this, see `:help bugs`. Basically, open an issue at the [bug tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues), or directly discuss this on the [vim_dev mailing list](https://www.vim.org/community.php).

Comment: `:echo has("balloon_multiline")` says 1, so I'm going to file the report as recommended.

Comment: If it only affects terminal windows, it's likely an oversight; the terminal stuff was only introduced recently.

Comment: For those interested: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/5193

Answer (score 0):

You may use list instead of string. For example, `balloon_show(['line1', 'line2'])`.

See also `:help balloon_show`:

```
balloon_show({expr})                    *balloon_show()*
        Show {expr} inside the balloon.  For the GUI {expr} is used as
        a string.  For a terminal {expr} can be a list, which contains
        the lines of the balloon.  If {expr} is not a list it will be
        split with |balloon_split()|.
        If {expr} is an empty string any existing balloon is removed.
```